# How to make scrape data only from article on some web-page using <p> and <div> tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have some issues with my scraper. I don't know, how to **scrape** only text without any service text like "Log in" "edit" and so on. I'm doing summarize project for my diploma project and it **scrape** articles from web-pages and files.

First, i've tried only to **scrape** "p" tags, but on some sites its not work correctly, because on these sites no "p" tags, where articles can be. Then i tried to **scrape** both "p" and "div". But now it **scrapes** absolutly everything, even things, i dont want to see in my text for summarize.

Here is module, which used for scraping text and articles from web-page:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs


def scrape(url):
    try:
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
        })
    except:
        return False

    scraped_data = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    article = scraped_data.read()

    parsed_article = bs.BeautifulSoup(article, 'lxml')

    paragraphs = parsed_article.find_all('p')
    text_in_no_p = parsed_article.find_all("div")

    article_text = ""

    for p in paragraphs:
        article_text += p.text

    for p in text_in_no_p:
        article_text += p.text

    return article_text
```

I expect to see scraped text without any service text like in example above. At least any text from main block of web page. I am not really good at web-scraping and know only some methods to do web scraping.
Thank you for any advice.

EDIT 1

For example, summarized text of wikipedia article(10 sentences) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Electric_Lightning

"^ Darling 2008, pp.
^ Lake 1997, pp.
Lightning T.4 Two-seat side-by-side training version, based on the F.1A; two prototypes and 20 production built, two aircraft later converted to T.5 prototypes, two aircraft later converted to T.54.
^ Darling 2000, pp.
[nb 1] This was a low-speed research aircraft and was designed so that different wing sweep angles could be assumed by the single aircraft.
^ a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u Lightning F Mk.6 Operating Data Manual.
^ Ellis 2012, p.278 ^ a b Ellis 2012, p. 91 ^ Ellis 2012, p. 294 ^ a b Ellis 2012, p.132 ^ a b "Aircraft Listing."
Prior testing had determined that the aircraft would have the excess thrust to achieve this speed, given the right atmospheric conditions of a high tropopause and lower-than-standard temperature.
"Teddy" Petter, formerly chief designer at Westland Aircraft, was a keen early proponent of Britain's need to develop a supersonic fighter aircraft.
On later variants of the Lightning, a ventral weapons pack could be installed to equip the aircraft alternatively with different armaments, including missiles, rockets, and cannons."

And expected output, but only scraped "p" tags(7 sentences and old version)

"[nb 1] This was a low-speed research aircraft and was designed so that different wing sweep angles could be assumed by the single aircraft.
When travelling beyond the Design Mach, the oblique shock would become supercritical, and supersonic airflow would enter the inlet duct, which could only handle subsonic air.
The specification for the aircraft followed the cancellation of the Air Ministry's 1942 E.24/43 supersonic research aircraft specification which had resulted in the Miles M.52 programme.
On later variants of the Lightning, a ventral weapons pack could be installed to equip the aircraft alternatively with different armaments, including missiles, rockets, and cannons.
"Teddy" Petter, formerly chief designer at Westland Aircraft, was a keen early proponent of Britain's need to develop a supersonic fighter aircraft.
The airframe absorbs heat from the surrounding air, the inlet shock cone at the front of the aircraft becoming the hottest part.
This performance and the initially limited fuel supply made the Lightning a "fuel-critical" aircraft, meaning that its missions are dictated to a high degree by its limited range.
"

Edit 2:
Main problem here, that if i **scrape** only text, from "p" tags, there must be a lot of problems with sites, where articles not in "p" tags. For example, my programm is quits while scraping from some sites. Some sites doesnt holds their articles in "p" tags. This really hard for me to make something like master key for sites, because commision would see, how my programm will works with "good" and "bad" sites. Thank you

Comment: Could you provide an example of input, and desired output please?

Comment: I added some edits

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ not scrap